# Can't connect to website on port 80 with Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Laravel Homestead for my development environment. I have it working at 192.168.0.141:8000, but I need it to work directly at just 192.168.0.141 (i.e. port 80). But it's just not working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I had it working months ago, but it's not working anymore.

Here's my `Homestead.yaml`:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox
ssl: true

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\John\Documents\Github\my-app
      to: /home/vagrant/my-app

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/my-app/public

networks:
    - type: "public_network"
      ip: "192.168.0.141"

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: false
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

Thank you

Comment: sometimes some other applications also use the same port. especially Skype. so just confirm the 80 port is not used by other process which is not ended yet.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Because I see no attempt to change the default port settings here. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#ports

Comment: Also why is this tagged `laravel-5`? Surely you aren't using that? It's been unsupported for years.

Comment: @miken32 I tried sending port 80 to 8000, but that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I don't see an attempt here, but why do you "need" it on port 80? You understand that this is for development use only? It's not a production server.

Comment: As part of many of my api calls, it returns urls to assets. These urls are of the format `http://192.168.0.141/some_image.png`. However, because I can't connect to port 80, these images don't actually load.

Comment: You should have `APP_URL` defined in your development environment's `.env` file to include the port number. I assume you are using proper functions such as `route()`, `url()`, and `asset()` to build URLs?

Comment: I tried changing it to `APP_URL=https://192.168.0.141:8000`, but the api is sending back `192.168.10.10`

Comment: Sorry, correction: it's sending back just `192.168.0.141`, without any port still

Comment: Then your code for generating URLs is incorrect. But also ensure you've cleared your config cache after making changes `php artisan optimize:clear`